# Export BYTE/GRAPHIC Data from Teradata

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, snowflake-connector

What is the best approach to export byte/graphic data from Teradata ? For a data migration project, can someone guide me on how to export data from teradata to snowflake. I am using TPT scripts and tdload approach, however, it doesn't seem to work.

Approach that I have followed :

1. Convert the data from byte to ASCII using FROM_BYTES() method in Teradata. However, during the ingestion process I was not able to get it bacl to original state.
2. Using FROM_BYTES() method with base10/base16 to get into the desired format, however, I am facing same issue with the process.

Below is Table structure :

```
CREATE SET TABLE DBC.AccessRights ,FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO,
     MAP = TD_DATADICTIONARYMAP
     (
      UserId BYTE(4) NOT NULL,
      DatabaseId BYTE(4) NOT NULL,
      TVMId BYTE(6) NOT NULL,
      FieldId SMALLINT FORMAT '---,--9' NOT NULL,
      AccessRight CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET LATIN UPPERCASE NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      WithGrant CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN UPPERCASE NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      GrantorID BYTE(4) NOT NULL,
      AllnessFlag CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN UPPERCASE NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      CreateUID BYTE(4),
      CreateTimeStamp TIMESTAMP(0),
      LastAccessTimeStamp TIMESTAMP(0),
      AccessCount INTEGER FORMAT '--,---,---,--9')
PRIMARY INDEX ( UserId )
PARTITION BY ( RANGE_N((ID2BIGINT(DatabaseId )) MOD  1073741824  BETWEEN 0  AND 1073741823  EACH 1 ),
RANGE_N(ID2BIGINT(TVMId ) BETWEEN 0  AND 4294967295.  EACH 1 )ADD 2 );
```

Tpt Script :

```
USING CHARACTER SET UTF8
DEFINE JOB EXPORT_DELIMITED_FILE
DESCRIPTION 'Export rows from a Teradata table to a unformatted file'  (  DEFINE SCHEMA FILE_SCHEMA  (
UserId BYTE(4),
DatabaseId BYTE(4),
TVMId BYTE(6),
FieldId SMALLINT,
AccessRight CHAR(4),
WithGrant CHAR(2),
GrantorID BYTE(4),
AllnessFlag CHAR(2),
CreateUID BYTE(4),
CreateTimeStamp TIMESTAMP(0),
LastAccessTimeStamp TIMESTAMP(0),
AccessCount INTEGER
);  

DEFINE OPERATOR SQL_SELECTOR
TYPE SELECTOR  SCHEMA FILE_SCHEMA ATTRIBUTES  
(
  VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'selector_log',  
  VARCHAR TdpId = <host_id>,
  VARCHAR UserName = <user_name>,

  VARCHAR UserPassword = <password>,,
  VARCHAR SelectStmt = 'SELECT * FROM DBC.AccessRights;',
  VARCHAR LobDirectoryPath = <lob_dir>
);  

DEFINE OPERATOR FILE_WRITER TYPE DATACONNECTOR CONSUMER SCHEMA *  ATTRIBUTES  
(  
 VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'dataconnector_log',
 VARCHAR DirectoryPath = <dir_path>,
 VARCHAR FileName = 'file.csv',
 VARCHAR FORMAT= 'BINARY',
 VARCHAR OpenMode = 'Write'
);  

APPLY TO OPERATOR (FILE_WRITER)
SELECT * FROM OPERATOR (SQL_SELECTOR);  
);
```

Comment: You keep re-asking essentially the same question. You should edit the existing question to include more information if you want an answer. What is the desired format / result? Can you provide a better / simpler / more concrete example than AccessRights?

Comment: Maybe "concrete" is the wrong word. More realistic? What value does a Teradata internal object ID have to a Snowflake implementation?

Comment: @Fred for data migration from teradata to snowflake, I need to transfer byte data to equivalent datatype in snowflake. I am planning to convert the BYTE data to ASCII or hexa format and then convert these type conversions back to the original form in snowflake.

Comment: @Fred I have edited the question and mentioned the approach that I have followed. The problem is I am not able to get the data back to the original state after converting the original data to the desired format (base10/base16/ascii). How should I handle that ? Is there any method to extract the byte data in original format rather than using conversions ?

Comment: You need to ask the SF guys how to convert a hex-string created by to_bytes+base16 into bytes.

Comment: Regarding the TPT script shown, BINRAY uses Teradata's internal format for export, I don't know if there's an easy way to read it in SF (maybe for some basic data types)

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake defaults to hex string representation for input/output of binary data. If you have TPT output DELIMITED format with a schema defined or generated as all VARCHAR fields, you won't be able to use `SELECT *` but you can use `FROM_BYTES` to generate the hex string. There are some quirks that are simple enough to work around as long as you are aware, namely

- If the high order bit of the BYTE value is set the returned value will be the two's complement preceded by a negative sign
- leading zeros are removed from the result string

But you can prefix a "positive, non-zero" byte, convert, and then remove the extra characters from the string.

```
SUBSTRING(FROM_BYTES('12'xb||DatabaseId, 'base16') FROM 3)
```